# How to make sub menus for nav link?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

Hi I am new to react and wanted to implement sub menus to my menu.

What I wanted was something like this Report > My report > MIS report

I am importing and using NavLink from react router dom.

The menu currently looks like this with no sub-menus:

This is my code where I am using the nav bar link:

```
export const mainListItems = (
  <List>
    <NavLink to="dashboard">
      <ListItem button>
        <ListItemIcon></ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" />
      </ListItem>
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink to="userform">
      <ListItem button>
        <ListItemIcon></ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Registration" />
      </ListItem>
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink to="">
      <ListItem button>
        <ListItemIcon></ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Report" />
      </ListItem>
    </NavLink>
  </List>
);
This is the link in my App.js

const App = () => (
  <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
      <Route path="/userform" component={UserForm} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />

      <Redirect from="/" to="signin" />
    </Switch>
  </HashRouter>
);
I need some direction in this. How do I implement my own sub menus
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao, for nested navigation you could use `ListItem` and `Collapse` components from Material UI like this:

```
       <ListItem button onClick={this.handleClick}>  // Report level
          <ListItemIcon>
            <InboxIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Report" />
          {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
        </ListItem>
        <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>  //first nested level
          <List component="div" disablePadding>
            <ListItem
              button
              style={styles.nested}
              onClick={this.handleClickSecondLevel}
            >
              <ListItemIcon>
                <StarBorder />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="My Report" />
              {openSecondLevel ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
            </ListItem>
            <Collapse in={openSecondLevel} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>  // second nested level
              <List component="div" disablePadding>
                <ListItem button style={styles.nestedSecondLevel}>
                  <ListItemIcon>
                    <StarBorder />
                  </ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText primary="MIS Report" />
                </ListItem>
              </List>
            </Collapse>
          </List>
        </Collapse>
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-4s2db?file=/demo.js) a codesandbox example using class component.

Comment: Hi Giovanni , Thanks again but could you provide a sandbox for the given code? If it is not too much to ask?

Comment: @sandeeppradhan I made it :) Is here https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-4s2db?file=/demo.js

Comment: Hi Giovanni thanks again but when I try to import it it gives nothing

Comment: I am exporting and importing a const icon so there lies a problem there?

Comment: To apply my code in yours, it just necessary to replace your ListItem with my ListItem (by keeping the NavLink). Another thing: I don't know what icon you are importing but according to your code, you are not inserting any icon in ListItemIcon. Try to do something like: `<ListItemIcon><StarBorder /></ListItemIcon>` and you should see a star icon close to ListItem

Comment: The one you provided in the answer right, not in the sandbox?

Comment: where do I put the consts and the functions in the sandbox

Comment: I also cannot put this.state in the const function provided

Comment: @sandeeppradhan it's hard to answer without seeing your code. Do you have a github repo to share ?

Comment: Yea I am creating a repo

Comment: Hi Giovanni, no I dont have the repo any other suggestions?

Comment: @sandeeppradhan you could make a codesandbox with essential part (navigation, part of your code that doesn't work) and explain with some comments where do you want the nested navigation.